# Display text inside input text while using Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

Below is my code. Selected text from dropdown is displaying beside input text.

How can I display that inside input text. This is because "holdOrder.CenterName" is out side beside input text

```
 <input type="text" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" ng-disabled="disabled" style="margin-top: 5px;" />
   {{holdOrder.CenterName}}
   <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
      <li ng-repeat="svCenter in holdOrder.Centers">
       <a href="" ng-click="setSelectedSC(svCenter)">{{svCenter.Fullname}}</a>
      </li>
   </ul>
```

Comment: Have you heard about ngModel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind `input` field with `holdOrder.CenterName` using `ng-model`

```
 <input type="text" ng-model="holdOrder.CenterName" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle"  ng-disabled="disabled" style="margin-top: 5px;" />
       <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
          <li ng-repeat="svCenter in holdOrder.Centers">
           <a href="" ng-click="setSelectedSC(svCenter)">{{svCenter.Fullname}}</a>
          </li>
       </ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. I have a question which is extension to this. I want to use typeahead in that input text and filter in the model. How can I do this ?

Comment: I know that. My question is how to filter in controller ?

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what you want to achieve with an example if possible, probably in another post.

Comment: Here is what I did. This is the basic one and it is working. My question is, in the below link, how to replace states with my model http://plnkr.co/edit/SjASFL8BkKdjLRxUlGVA?p=preview